# Will my code prevent SQL injection

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

i have searched and added some prevention code but i need expert advice am i correct ?

I have made seperate file for SQL connect but i have confusion whether i should use include, require, include_onces or any other ?

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "userr", "pass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("databse") or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Here i have added two things `UTF8` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
$bad='anyone123';

$var = mysql_real_escape_string($bad);
$q = mysql_query('SET user_id UTF8');
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fbusers WHERE user_id = '$var'");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

Please give me advice if how can i prevent injec. to 100%
i don't want my website to be hacked :(

Thank you

Comment: Use pdo instead of mysql_ for a start

Comment: or mysqli, since mysql is deprecated

Comment: What is the problem in mysql ? i have coded my website in mysql :(

Comment: @user2615947 you only need to search and remove mysql_* methods with mysqli_*

Comment: There is a clear statement at [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) (which you should be referring to often) that the mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Comment: @furier Yes mysql to mysqli i can do... that anymore advice ??

Comment: will mysqli 100% prevent injections ??

Comment: The only thing that will prevent injections for sure is using parametrized queries, whether in mysqli or PDO.  Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prepared statements for any queries that require user input. This sends the query and the parameters seperately and acts as a layer of security to catch any malicious input.

In PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fbusers WHERE user_id = :var");

$stmt->execute(array(':var'=>$var));
```

In mysqli:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM fbusers WHERE user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $var);

$stmt->execute();
```

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) would help.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could give in mysqli rather then pdo